# Help me interpret this output from `top`

Tags: performance, top

This is from a Raspberry Pi B+. I am not sure whether it is overloaded and pegged to the max or whether it's doing ok. Too much information.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're having a hard time deciphering the output of `top`, you might like `htop`.

Anyway, `man top` will tell you:

```
2. SUMMARY Display
       Each  of the following three areas are individually controlled through one or more interactive commands.  See topic 4b. SUMMARY
       AREA Commands for additional information regarding these provisions.

   2a. UPTIME and LOAD Averages
       This portion consists of a single line containing:
           program or window name, depending on display mode
           current time and length of time since last boot
           total number of users
           system load avg over the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes

   2b. TASK and CPU States
       This portion consists of a minimum of two lines.  In an SMP environment, additional lines can reflect individual CPU state per‐
       centages.

       Line 1 shows total tasks or threads, depending on the state of the Threads-mode toggle.  That total is further classified as:
           running; sleeping; stopped; zombie

       Line 2 shows CPU state percentages based on the interval since the last refresh.

       As  a default, percentages for these individual categories are displayed.  Where two labels are shown below, those for more re‐
       cent kernel versions are shown first.
           us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
           sy, system  : time running kernel processes
           ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
           id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
           wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
           hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
           si : time spent servicing software interrupts
           st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor

       In the alternate cpu states display modes, beyond the first tasks/threads line, an abbreviated summary is shown  consisting  of
       these elements:
                      a    b     c    d
           %Cpu(s):  75.0/25.0  100[ ...

       Where: a) is the combined us and ni percentage; b) is the sy percentage; c) is the total; and d) is one of two visual graphs of
       those representations.  See topic 4b. SUMMARY AREA Commands and the `t' command for  additional  information  on  that  special
       4-way toggle.
```

In your case, the cpu has spent 64.2% of the time in the kernel idle handler.